# Why getting org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! when joining 3 tables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have three entity basicInfo, gender and department. If I join with basicInfo and gender model then it works fine but when want to join department along with other two entities same time then showing

> .QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!

**My Three entity classes here,**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employeebasicinfo")
public class BasicInfoModel {
@Id private String employeeId;
@NotBlank private String firstName;
@NotBlank private String lastName;
@NotNull private Integer companyId;
@Transient private String companyName;
private String phoneNo;

@Column(name = "sex")
private char sexId;

@Transient private String sexName;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date birthDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date joiningDate;

@NotNull private Integer department;
@Transient private String departmentName;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "sex", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private GenderModel genderModel;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(
  name = "department",
  referencedColumnName = "id",
  insertable = false,
  updatable = false)
private DepartmentModel departmentModel;
// getter setter
 }
```

**Gender Model**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "gender")
 public class GenderModel implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 private char id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;
 //getter setter
}
```

**And Department model**

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "department")
   public class DepartmentModel {
   @Id private int id;
   private String name;
   //getter setter
}
```

**My Dto class**

```
public class BasicInfoDto {
  private String employeeId;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private Integer companyId;
  private String companyName;
  private String phoneNo;
  private char sexId;
  private String sexName;
  private Date birthDate;
  private Date joiningDate;
  private Integer department;
  private String departmentName;


  public BasicInfoDto(char sexId, String sexName, int department, String departmentName) {
    this.sexId = sexId;
    this.sexName = sexName;
    this.department = department;
    this.departmentName = departmentName;

   //getter setter
  }
```

**My Repository class is below:**

```
@Repository
public interface BasicInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<BasicInfoModel, String> {


  @Query(
      value =
          "SELECT  new com.employeeAttendance.employeeAttendance.dto.BasicInfoDto ("
              + " a.sexId, b.name, a.department,c.name) FROM "
              + " BasicInfoModel a INNER JOIN GenderModel b on a.sexId = b.id" +
                   " INNER JOIN DepartmentMode c on a.department = c.id")
  List<BasicInfoDto> getBasicInfoList();
}
```

**And finally I am getting this error**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for
>   join! [SELECT  new
>   com.employeeAttendance.employeeAttendance.dto.BasicInfoDto ( a.sexId,
>   b.name, a.department,c.name) FROM 
>   com.employeeAttendance.employeeAttendance.model.BasicInfoModel a INNER
>   JOIN com.employeeAttendance.employeeAttendance.model.GenderModel b on
>   a.sexId = b.id INNER JOIN DepartmentMode c on a.department = c.id]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:713)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
>         ... 76 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT  new
>   com.employeeAttendance.employeeAttendance.dto.BasicInfoDto ( a.sexId,
>   b.name, a.department,c.name) FROM 
>   com.employeeAttendance.employeeAttendance.model.BasicInfoModel a INNER
>   JOIN com.employeeAttendance.employeeAttendance.model.GenderModel b on
>   a.sexId = b.id INNER JOIN DepartmentMode c on a.department = c.id]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:277)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:595)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:704)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>         ... 84 common frames omitted

However, if I remove 2nd join with department then it work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working on the entity properties in jpql not on tables. So you only tell jpql which property to use to join:

```
"SELECT  new com.employeeAttendance.employeeAttendance.dto.BasicInfoDto ("
  + " a.sexId, b.name, a.department,c.name) FROM "
  + " BasicInfoModel a INNER JOIN a.genderModel b "
  + " INNER JOIN a.departmentModel c";
```